# C# - Utilize cached Windows Credentials (WinForms)

Tags: c#, active-directory, networkcredentials

Is there a way to use the current user's credentials in C# without actually getting the values?

Using `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` for example, or whatever method may work.

I looked around for a bit but can't find much detailing exactly what I want to do.

Essentially I'm just looking for my app to AD authenticate with the current user's information - kind of how Outlook can detect the current user and set up automatically without prompting for user/pass.

Or for example if in my app I have an email feature, and instead of prompting for a user/pass to send an email - I can just pass the cached credentials.

That sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are utilizing AD/Kerberos, read up on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/principal-and-identity-objects

- Useful if you want to see if the User account is associated with an OU, CN, Group, or even Branch in AD.

If you are basically using WorkGroups, then: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment(v=vs.110).aspx

- Useful for acquiring basic HTTPRequest based information; IP, Domain, UserName, Workstation Name, etc.

Those are pretty much your only two reliable choices.

I have used both types of Auth Acquisitions to get certain pieces of information, pending on the infrastructure and use.